# Edit ssh_config without ssh connection on a remote VPS

Tags: root, privileges, ssh-config, non-root-user

Yesterday, I was busy setting up a remote server and securing it. I am a noob at code, programming and webhosting, but I am trying to host my own website.

So yesterday I changed some settings in the `sshd_config` file. One of the lines i changed was `PermitRootLogin`. I have that set to `no` right now.

Now I want to login to my server again, to make more changes, but the login method I am used to:

```
ssh root@server_IP
```

gives me the output:

```
Permission denied
```

I can't login to my remote server anymore how I used to. So as far as I know off, I can only connect to my server with my SFTP account, but that doesn't allow me to really update the server and install new software etc.

So how can I connect to my server again, as `root` user? I don't know how to open the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file since I am not connected as the `root` user to my server.

Comment: typically through a rescue system or virtual terminal that your VPS hoster provides

Comment: When you make a change to sshd_config, you can keep your current session open and test that your changes don't prevent you to login again. But I guess you'd do that now.

Comment: is there any other user on the system? if so, does that user have sudo privileges?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question depends on the exact configuration of your server, but ***if***

- you can log in as another user on that server (e.g. you mentioned an SFTP user: check if that that user is also allowed to login using a "regular" SSH session, and not restricted to SFTP connections), *and*
- your server configuration allows becoming `root` via password-based authentication (i.e. you are not restricted to using SSH keys)

then you should be able to become `root` via `su`.

So, the steps would be:

- Log on using your "normal" user account

  ```
  local_user@local_computer:~$ ssh normal_user@server_IP
  normal_user@server_IP's password:
  ```
- Become `root`:

  ```
  normal_user@server_IP:~$ su -
  Password:
  root@server_IP:~#
  ```
- Edit the `sshd_config` as root

If the `root` user is prevented from password-based authentication, you will need to have a "normal" user account with `sudo` privileges. In that case:

- Log on using your "normal" user account.
- Edit the `sshd_config` via `sudo`:

  ```
  normal_user@server_IP:~$ sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  ```

If none of the above apply, you may need to contact your web provider for assistance.